# NodeJs Assertion failed on HTTP call (Mac)

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

```
var client = require('http');
var endpoint = apiEndpoint;
var request = client.get(endpoint, function(responseFromApi) {
            var responseString = '';
            responseFromApi.setEncoding('utf-8');
            responseFromApi.on('data', function(data) {
                responseString += data;
            });

            // To reformat the string response into Json...
            responseFromApi.on('end', function() {
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(responseString);
                callback(jsonResponse);
            });
        });
```

I am making API calls using the method above, however on random instances my call fails due to the Assertion fail like below. Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

```
Assertion failed: (handle->type == UV_TCP || handle->type == UV_TTY || handle->type == UV_NAMED_PIPE), function uv___stream_fd, file ../deps/uv/src/unix/stream.c, line 1568.
```

Environment: Mac, Nodejs

Note: I have tested the same code on an AWS lambda server and never faced this issue. I am guessing this is a Mac only instance. Lord Google informed me that it is a Mac desync issue.

Same is true if trying to get data from a dynamoDB sitting on Amazon server using the code below...

```
 // To get userID.
            var userId = getUserIdFromContext(this);
            if (!userId) {
                callback('userId is not set.');
            } 

            // To get table name.
            var table = constants.dynamoDBTableName;
            if(!table) {
                callback('DynamoDB Table name is not set.');
            }

            // To set the DocumentClient.
            if(!doc) {
                doc = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
            }

            // To set the params.
            var params = {
                Key: {
                    CustomerId: userId
                },
                TableName: table,
                ConsistentRead: true
            };

            // To get data from table.
            var skillContext = this;
            doc.get(params, function(err, data){
                if(err) {
                    console.log('get error: ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    if(isEmptyObject(data)) {
                        callback('The object is empty.');
                    } else {
                        var userData = JSON.parse(data.Item['Data']);
                        extractUserData(skillContext, userData, callback);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: have you tried replacing the http library with npm request and trying the tests? also have you checked the headers from your Lambda pipeline and compare them to your local test?

Comment: yes! same result. :(

Comment: I npm installed jquery and it throws the error like below:-   TypeError: require(...).jsdom(...).createWindow is not a function
    at create (/Users/varun.goyal/tools/repos/accwx-amazon-skills/src/node_modules/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js:5:39)

Comment: @VarunGoyal check your `.on('error', (e) => {})` handler to see if you can find more info there

Comment: I did, got nothing, I am guessing this error shows up even before the call is made to my server

Comment: It works for me on mac & NodeJS 6.5